# How to add jetifier in app inventor platform

Tags: android, compiler-errors, app-inventor

hi so im trying to add jetifier to my app inventor source 
i recently added D8 dexer from here https://github.com/pavi2410/appinventor-sources/tree/d8 and migrate to androidX then i faced a problem whith android support which makes me need to add jetifier
So i followed this to add jetifier
https://github.com/pavi2410/appinventor-sources/tree/ucr-29
but since i changed to D8 the codes in tthat tree doesn't exist anymore 
i want to start jetifier function from compiler.java file and the codes in another file

that is the code that were presented in the tree

> DexExecTask dexTask = new DexExecTask();
>   List jetifierClasspath = new ArrayList<>(); for (String path : JETIFIER_CP) { jetifierClasspath.add(getResource(JETIFIER_DIR + path)); } dexTask.setJetifierClasspath(Joiner.on(File.pathSeparatorChar).join(jetifierClasspath));

i added `DexExecTask dexTask = new DexExecTask();` to it but this lines doesn't started it 
jetifier codes located at DexExecTask.java

if you can please could you guide me how to start in while compiling the apk ?

hope i made it clear
thnx

Comment: you might want to ask in the App Inventor Open Source community here https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/c/open-source-development/10

Comment: @Taifun i asked but no response

Comment: everything has already been said here https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/d8-with-jetifier/9865/4?u=taifun